# Reflecting a decorator pattern in mysql database table

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns, decorator

I am working with a mysql database and java. My understanding of the decorator pattern is that it allows for very flexible runtime because you can just assign as many decorators as you want until you get the behaviour or representation of the object that you want.   I have successfully programmed several decorators before, now I would like to store the state of my decorated object into a database (preferably mysql).  For example:

Suppose I am coding a system for a coffee shop and my model for representing the cost of beverages uses a decorator (ie. concrete object is espresso and it can be decorated with milk, sugar, whip cream, syrup and whatever else they put in coffee these days.)  Furthermore, suppose I cannot at this time anticipate how many different ingredients I can have in my coffee in the future (maybe someday people will want jelly beans in their coffee, but I don't know that yet)

Now I want to record every time someone buys a drink, and keep track of the ingredients that were used.  What is the best way to design my database schema so that it can handle new ingredients as they appear.  I currently have two ideas, neither of which seems like the correct way to go about it:

1)  Encode the drink as a json string that and just dump it in the database, assume my data access objects can handle decoding this.

2)  Try to anticipate all possible modifications to the drinks and make columns for each of these, every time someone comes up with a new beverage add on I have to alter the schema.

There must be a better approach than either of these.

Comment: The decorator pattern is designed to add *behavior* to a class.  Your problem is simple addition.  Just store the "decorations" as additional ingredients in your database, and add them to the coffee as needed.  If new ingredients appear, they can be added to the database as new ingredient records.

Comment: Using two tables: Dish (or a better name like Beverage) and Ingredients maybe?

Comment: You need a `many-to-many` relationship between `Beverage` and `Ingredients`. The various attributes specific to *one particular* drink (order ID, discount or whatever) might be stored as attribute of the relation.

Comment: This will probably http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf831 get you on the right track. assuming it's a coffee shop where you can only buy coffee and its not a dutch version off a coffee shop... with this schema you can add easy new types and calc stats / total costs on it.

Comment: @RaymondN with the added constraint, that, if I understand it well, *each* coffee might have 0 to many extra *ingredients*.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux yes you mean random ingredients (decorates) know on for hand.. trust me 90% of the people in the netherlands that is will decorate (drink) there coffee "black", "sugar", "sugar with milk", "milk".  your really better off when you add new types records based vs columns.   Only problem that is you can add "sugar with milk" and "milk with sugar" there is no check on that should be checked manually in the software. Databases can't handle random schema's so you should live with it that is probably the best way to go

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux  KEY(coffee_type_id, coffee_decorator_id) is meant as a convering index not a constraint http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/569b06. and you think foreach or object based..   think a customer orders a coffee and could decorate or not. The customer_order is the main thing here so thats why ive added a coffee_type_id and coffee_decorator_id there.

Comment: If Simon Diemert really wants to have a database that models the real thing he should use the FCO-IM method to create the tables that he needs.

Comment: Didn't think about using secondary tables to store this....sigh...its friday.  Thanks everyone.  Also, love the sqlfiddle, thanks @Sylvain Leroux.

Comment: @SimonDiemert It's not me! It's Raymond ;) Definitively Friday for everyone :D

Answer (score 1):

Try using 3 tables for this, one for the ingredients, one for the order, and a lookup table between the two. Each time an order is created you add one row to orders and many rows to orders_ingredients

```
create table orders {
   order_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   order_name 
);

create table orders_ingredients {
   order_id references orders(order_id)
   ingredient_id references ingredients(ingredient_id)
);

create table ingredients {
   ingredient_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   ingredient_name varchar(255)
);
```