# Reverse Decorator Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I would like to dynamically add new product data to database. The users go through various list selections (where they can select an existing value or add new) to categorize a product and in the and add a price and size. The categorization order is as follows:

**Category->Subcategory->Producer->Product**

E.g. A user can choose an existing category and subcategory, but add a new product by a new producer. So the new data which should be added to DB will be product and producer data.
If the ordering of selections would be reverse:

Product->Producer->Subcategory->Category

The base product would be set at the beginning and a normal Decorator Pattern would work, but in reverse order I don't see how.

Could someone tell me how would I do this the right way?

Comment: The Decorator pattern is about adding behaviors to your classes, I don’t see it in your case. To clarify that you can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278465/reflecting-a-decorator-pattern-in-mysql-database-table

Comment: I was planning on using Category, Subcategory and Producer as Decorators. For each decorator a new value has to be added to the database

Comment: What does any of this have to do with the decorator pattern?